Angular 17 will not run if not on C drive
I have an angular app that, when build and run, gets stuck on:

Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)

It is a simple start template, to which I haven't done anything yet. When trying to build and serve it, it does not work if it is on the E drive. If I move it to the C drive then it does.
I have tried to:

remove and reinstall the angular CLI,
clear the cache and remove the node_modules folder,
restart VS Code and restart the PC

Nothing worked.
How can I solve this problem?

Do you have prerendering enabled ? (check your angular.json)
